# Build whenever a new commit happen , Jenkins + github?

Tags: git, jenkins, github

We have a master branch, on which developer creates branches as feature/US-**** and then commit and push the feature branch to git.

There can be multiple feature branches for one master branch.

Now this is where I need to trigger the build. (On creation of new feature branch and on every commit/push).

I have a setup where I am polling my SCM for every `H/5 * * * *` and I have kept,

```
Branch Specifier (blank for 'any') = */feature/*
Refspec = +refs/heads/feature/*:refs/remotes/feature/*
```

But this still print log as :

```
Seen branch in repository origin/master....
```

Whereas I need to trigger build on feature branch creation and on every commit on those feature branch.
Also it should not pickup those branches which has already been merged with the master?

Is this setup possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely possible. The best setup I've personally used is a git webhooks. You can specify what events to fire events from in the webhook configuration screen: [webhook example config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ENUS.png)

You'll need the jenkins github plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin

Then you just point github to your jenkins instance as the webhook endpoint and configure the trigger on your job to be triggered by the hook. Example: [Jenkins githook configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhJTj.png)

Bonus note: If you are like me and have a private jenkins instance in aws you'll have to do some fanciness with lambda and api-gateway to get github to hook in correctly. I used this code to do it: https://github.com/pristineio/lambda-webhook

Comment: I tried the webhook logic, it works perfectly well,  but the issue is even if I have kept the branch specifier as `*/feature/*` it still triggers when changes are pushed to master. I have edited the webhook to `Branch or tag creation` and `Branch or tag deletion` and `Pushes`, but as the branch specifier has feature it should not have triggered on push to master. Right?